# Favicon: .ico or .png / correct tags?

Tags: html, png, favicon, ico

In a HTML5 document, which favicon format do you recommend and why? I want it to be supported by IE7 and all the modern browsers.

Also, when using .png, do I need to specify the type (type="image/png")?

Answer (score 545, accepted):

<s>For compatibility with all browsers stick with `.ico`.</s>

.png is getting more and more support though as it is easier to create using multiple programs.

for .ico

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

for .png, you need to specify the type

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/image.png" />
```

Comment: Is it alright to include both and let the browser decide which to use?

Comment: Thank you. But in HTML5 you don't need to self-close the tag, right?

Comment: @Richard: You are free to choose if you want to self-close in HTML5.

Comment: @ewall: Yes, that is possible. However, I'd add the `type` attribute for the ico variant, too.

Comment: @unor So that would be `type="image/x-icon"`

Comment: Current PNG favicon support in browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-png

Comment: "For compatibility with all browsers stick with .ico." Was valid when this was answered back in the depths of history, today PNG use is perfectly compatible with everything. (This is a problem that occurs more and more on SO… answers don't always age well)

Comment: yeah, every modern browser supports .png *(getting favicon.png in ie7 is impossible)*

Comment: It's 2022, I'm 11 years older and we still don't know how to create .ico files. Stick with PNG.

Comment: "shortcut icon" is not used anymore, just use "icon" for the rel attribute.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel
"Note: The shortcut link type is often seen before icon, but this link type is non-conforming, ignored and web authors must not use it anymore."

Comment: what happens if we don't specify type? Any issues?

Answer (score 44):

See here: [Cross Browser favicon](http://www.kevinleary.net/how-to-add-cross-browser-favicon-website/)

Thats the way to go:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.example.com/image.png"><!-- Major Browsers -->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.example.com/alternateimage.ico"/><![endif]--><!-- Internet Explorer-->
```

Comment: Do you think that `shortcut icon` in lower case would work? (We never know with IE)

Comment: @Mageek Never tested it with lower case.

Comment: safari for iOS also does not support .png according to [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=ico)

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Safari for iOS doesn't use Favicons at all so it's not a concern.

Comment: @mrvautin, it's not quite right. Safari for iOS does support icons, but they are disabled by default. You can enable them in the Safari settings.

Comment: Microsoft has “retired” its Internet Explorer on June 15, 2022

Answer (score 44):

I know this is an old question.

Here's another option - attending to different platform requirements - [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049636/adding-apple-icon-to-website)

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/vnd.microsoft.icon' href='/favicon.ico'> <!-- IE -->
<link rel='apple-touch-icon' type='image/png' href='/icon.57.png'> <!-- iPhone -->
<link rel='apple-touch-icon' type='image/png' sizes='72x72' href='/icon.72.png'> <!-- iPad -->
<link rel='apple-touch-icon' type='image/png' sizes='114x114' href='/icon.114.png'> <!-- iPhone4 -->
<link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/icon.114.png'> <!-- Opera Speed Dial, at least 144×114 px -->
```

This is the broadest approach I have found so far.

Ultimately the decision depends on your own needs. Ask yourself, who is your target audience?

**UPDATE May 27, 2018:** As expected, time goes by and things change. But there's good news too. I found a tool called [Real Favicon Generator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) that generates all the required lines for the icon to work on all modern browsers and platforms. It doesn't handle backwards compatibility though.

Comment: I wish we could have it somewhat standardized. But, if wishes were fishes we'd all swim in riches. I found this is the best approach. Thanks for it.

Comment: this is a good response, but its hard to create each of this files, https://realfavicongenerator.net/ does this for us, i recommend it

Comment: @rocketsarefast - way to come after a 4 year old comment