# Adding Apple Icon To Website

Tags: html, favicon

I have tested my site with Woorank and shows a warning about missing of the Apple Icon.

I have searched but I'm not sure how to include this icon, I have found this code

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-iphone4.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-ipad-retina.png" />
```

Must I include these lines in the head in the same way of the standard favicon? (My website is in HTML5)

What is the resolution of the first images in these lines *"apple-touch-iphone.png"*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The smallest icon should be 57×57 pixel.

Be aware, that the "-precomposed" states, that the linked icon file is already shiny and in 3D. If you leave out "-precomposed", iOS will add a 3D brilliance effect to the image.

And yes, of course do you need to insert the `link`-tags to the `head`.

Example for a complete icon set:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="icon.57.png"><!-- iPhone -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" sizes="72x72" href="icon.72.png"><!-- iPad -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" sizes="114x114" href="icon.114.png"><!-- iPhone4 -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon.114.png"><!-- Opera Speed Dial, at least 144×114 px -->
```

Docs on Apple iOS icons: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Docs on Opera Speed Dial icon: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-speed-dial-enhancements/

Comment: Thanks. I have not read the rest because I have found this piece of code in another question without the link to a full Apple documentation.