# Favicon not being displayed

Tags: favicon

My image is not showing up. I cleared cache but no luck. Image is verified in the same folder. Not working on Chrome or Safari.

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="TabBarLogo.png" sizes="16x16">

</head>
```

also tried `rel="shortcut icon"`

Comment: @Nisarg tab bar icon - ie. favicon. Not image.

Comment: u mean favicon for the browser? , perhaps try locating ur image in your folder, it might not exist

Comment: see also this SO-Post (+answers): 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121725/favicon-ico-or-png-correct-tags

Comment: From my experience, the favicon is cached outside of the normal browser cache and will not be reloaded when the cache is cleared. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Comment: Try `rel="shortcut icon"`

Comment: tried that already

Comment: Your code is valid, Try opening the page in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<head>` directly after fixed my problem. With no HTML code in between.

1.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

2.)

```
<head></head>
```